# Noob JSP + Servlet + EJB information for building J2EE simple web project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am new to Java. Covered basics and now jumping into making a simple web project. Project with functionality as below

1- CSS and Javascript use.

2- Managing user information (Add, Update, Delete, List)

3- Login form (Pass username, password and authenticate to create cookie)

4- Success/failure page.

That's what I want to make. I have lots of ASP.NET experience so its better to learn from making a project.

I need help like

1- Anyone know any open source web project from which I can learn to complete above tasks.

2- Any good latest J2EE 6 books to cover JSP, Servlts and EJB to make website.

3- Any video tutorials.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the netbeans ide there are lots of [tutorials, articles and screencasts](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html)

BTW CSS and Javascript are strictly speaking implementation details not functionality.